# How can I save JSP default editor configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-plugin, editor

I have used both Eclipse 2020-12 and 2021-03 version.

When I set JSP default editor, it works well until I close Eclipse.
But close Eclipse and restart Eclipse, it returns initial setup even if I remove '*.jsp' configuration. I don't know why it can't be changed. Exactly, it isn't saved.

I did as below.

1. Window - Preferences - General - Editors - File Associations.
2. Click *.jsp
3. Click JSP Editor as default
4. Click 'Apply and Close'

[Default]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIn1x.png)

[Edit]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nL9Y.png)

Also I have tried modifying a file of Eclipse configuration.

- Path : [workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/
- File name : org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs

[Default]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmOkz.png)

[Edit]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKtCH.png)

But it didn't work.

Both Eclipse 2020-12 and 2021-03 version are same situation.

Is there any other way to try solving this problem?

Whenever I use Eclipse, I always have to set JSP default editor as 'JSP Editor'.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to report against the Platform. Is it opening the Generic Text Editor by default as the preferences show?

Comment: Yes. The Generic Text Editor is default editor of jsp files. So it's hard to see my codes. I always change the default editor when I open the Eclipse.

Comment: That's not exactly the thing I asked, but it still sounds like a bug in the Platform that should be reported.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. You're right. When I open a jsp file, the editor is the Generic Text Editor NOT JSP Editor. You mean this bug report website, bugs.eclipse.org/bugs, right?

Comment: Yes, and AFAIK the Generic Text Editor has (and will have) zero support for JSPs.

Comment: You don't have more than one JSP content type, do you?

Comment: You mean in the list of File types of File Associations?

Comment: No, on the Content Types preference page.

Comment: I have many content types. *.class, *.html, *.pom and so on.